# How to dynamically adjust the size of the title in NavigationPage.TitleView in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I use NavigationPage.TitleView to make the title a certain size, I set it to 18. But in some cases my titles are too big to show at all. So I want to adjust it automatically depending on the size. How can I do this?

**This is my NavigationPage.TitleView**

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <Label
        x:Name="navlabel"
        FontSize="18"
        Text="{Binding nextTitle}"
        TextColor="White" />
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

And this is what I'm currently using in the constructor to drop the title

```
    public stepView(string title, string chapterTitle)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //get current title
        navlabel.Text = title + " - " + chapterTitle;
    }
```

How can I make this possible?

Comment: You want the title 1) to continue to a new line, 2) truncate it or 3) make the font size smaller?

Comment: yes that is what i want @stersym

Comment: I had done a demo and found that if I didn't set the font size, the titie will show completely even though it is a long text. This maybe the easiest way. In addition, if you want to set the font size and auto fit it too, you may need to custom the navigation  renderer in both android and ios.